# Jest 24.1 and babel 7.3.3 still problems with most tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

Ok, I've been breaking my head over this for a few days now. So I finally will ask the fine folks at StackOverflow for much needed help :)

[Here is the error I'm getting => Identifier 'global' has already been declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkaGA.png)

[And it seems to not recognize the require keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKfK8.png)

So at the moment, 50% of the test suite passes.

It seems to only be thrown in tests where redux reducers are called. As the error is the same for almost all the failing tests.

Here is my current `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    const isTest = api.env('test')

    const presets = [
        isTest && [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
        [
            'next/babel',
            {
                'preset-env': {},
                'transform-runtime': {},
                'styled-jsx': {},
                'class-properties': {},
            },
        ],
    ].filter(Boolean)

    const plugins = ['babel-plugin-styled-components']

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
        sourceType: 'unambiguous',
    }
}
```

And the dependencies are at

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
        "@cypress/snapshot": "^2.0.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "cypress": "^3.1.5",
        "eslint": "^5.14.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.2.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.0.1",
        "husky": "^1.3.1",
        "jest": "^24.1.0",
        "jest-canvas-mock": "^1.1.0",
        "jest-dom": "^3.1.2",
        "next-progressbar": "^1.0.0",
        "nock": "^10.0.6",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
        "prettier": "1.16.1",
        "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
        "react-testing-library": "^5.9.0",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
        "require-all": "^3.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing the "babel-jest" dependency ?
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

Comment: As indicated by a previous comment, it's fairly difficult to help if there's no [mcve] to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GoGoris I have included the full devDependencies, and babel-jest is at the latest version as well.

Comment: @g00glen00b Agree, this may be too little info, will setup a codesandbox to reproduce it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I fixed it by now, it wasn't a problem with jest or babel.
I had what I would guess, a reserved name as a variable, where it would throw a confusing error since the lastest babel.

[image: This was the fix! :)]